# pg_restore runs normally but fails to restore any data

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb, pg-restore

First of, I'm using timescaledb with PostgreSQL 15, the database I am trying to restore was made using timescaledb so I am using their instructions to restore the database.

I go through the motions, have a bit of difficulty making timescaledb get preloaded but after I do the process runs as expected up until I use \pg_restore. The exact command I use is

`\! pg_restore -Fc -U postgres -d newdb "C:\example\file\path\bin\dumpfile.sql"`

this is a bit different than the one used in the timescale DB example but this one asks me for the user "postgres"'s password (otherwise it asks for the computer user's password which doesn't exist)

I get a warning for an invalid date of creation and get prompted for the password, I type it and press enter, and then nothing, no error messages, no messages of tables being loaded. I type `\d` no tables, I've looked in pgadmin just to make sure. It simply does nothing and expects a new command. it looks like this

```
newdb=# \! pg_restore -Fc -U postgres -d newdb "C:\example\file\path\bin\dumpfile.sql"
pg_restore: warning: invalid creation date in header
Password:
newdb=#
```

I have been able to restore the same exact file I am trying to restore right now, but that was in another computer running on Windows 11 (the one I'm trying this in runs on Windows 10) so I know what should be displaying it just isn't in this case. I'm not sure how relevant the version of Windows is since the person I am collaborating with also uses windows 10

Comment: i think the configuration is different, your windows 11 installation allows invalid dates, you must change the configuration, or replace all invalid dates

Comment: @nbk would that be datestyle in the conf file? or are you taking about a different setting

Comment: 1) Well this `newdb=# \! pg_restore - ...` is a big oops. `pg_restore` is a command line client that needs to run outside of `psql` in the OS shell. 2) What is the exact command that created  `dumpfile.sql`?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I don't have the command that created the ```dumpfile.sql``` as for the  ```\! pg_restore``` command, it worked before in psql, it's just not working now, I also tried using powershell to execute it, and the same thing happened, though maybe I should try it without executing psql first. though again, that's just the instructions for using ```pg_restore``` according to the timescaledb documentation

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I did it through powershell with the command ```.\pg_restore.exe -Fc -U postgres -d newdb dumpfile.sql``` the same thing happened

Comment: 1) You went through all the steps previous to the pg_restore as shown here [Backup/Restore](https://docs.timescale.com/self-hosted/latest/backup-and-restore/pg-dump-and-restore/)? 2) Are the timescaledb versions the same for the database dumped as the one restored? 3) The only place I could the find the error message *invalid creation date in header* in the Postgres source is `pg_backup_archiver.c` and it related to incorrect timezones. You might want to check the `TimeZone` setting in postgresql.conf for the various installations. In `psql` the command `show timezone;` will return that.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver 1) yes for all the ones relating to pg_restore, 2) I have to assume so, idk what version it was dumped from, but it worked once before with the same version I'm running now, 3) it's not an error for me, it's a warning, the same warning showed up in the other computer i tried doing this on, I'll need to ask  about the timezone to know for sure

Comment: Wondering if the restore is being done to a schema that is not on your `search_path`? In `psql` do `\dn` to see what schemas are in that database. If there is more then one then you can do `\d<schema_name".* to see if the tables are there.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver there are no tables there, neither in the public schema, where, it appeared before nor on any timescaledb related schema. aside from those there aren't any other schemas in the database

Comment: The only idea I have left is look at the Postgres log to see if there are any clues there.